# Io_obj*(istream&) as a pointer to function in Stroustrup

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, using, stdmap

In The C++ Programming Language (p.650 of Fourth Edition paperback), Stroustrup writes some code for a map with a string as the key and function pointer as the mapped type (comment is his own):

```
using Pf = Io_obj*(istream&); // pointer to function returning an Io_obj*
std::map<std::string,Pf> io_map;
```

I am not really familiar with function pointers and I wanted to make my own test code where you have a string like "add 1 2", break off the first word to pass as the key to map, and pass the remainder as the argument to the calculating function pointer that map returns. My types are simpler (plain old int and plain old string) but it took me some googling to get it into a form the compiler would accept. Leaving out the alias here for simplicity:

```
std::map<std::string,int(std::string)> calc_map; // Stroustrup's syntax (comipile error)...
```

became...

```
std::map<std::string,int(*)(std::string)> calc_map; // syntax that compiles...
```

Question 1: Is this some idiosyncratic issue with clang (I am on an old Mac laptop because my linux machine is dead!) or did Stroustrup forget to add the (*) in his example? Am I missing something else?

Further, his example uses an alias, which in my simple calculation example translated at first to:

```
using Pf = int(std::string); // compiler actually seems to think this is fine
std::map<std::string,Pf> calc_map; // compiler does not like this
```

and when fixed became...

```
using Pf = int(*)(std::string); // compiler thinks this is fine too
std::map<std::string,Pf> calc_map; // compiler also likes this and everything works
```

Question 2: What kind of thing is an int(std::string) that the compiler doesn't mind it as an alias?

Possibly useful version stuff from clang:

```
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, it is not an issue with clang.`int(std::string)` is a function type. `int(*)(std::string)` is a function pointer type. Pointers are objects, functions are not. You cannot put a non-object in a map. You should be able to read about this stuff in a book about C++.

Comment: I think you missed something. The "function type" syntax you just wrote is the syntax Stroustrup uses IN HIS BOOK ON C++: Io_obj*(istream&). He describes it in his comment as "pointer to function returning an Io_obj*" and his example code doesn't compile. This is why I asked the Internet. My book which I am reading had an error in it.

Comment: That looks like a bug in the book. On the other hand, the book does refer to a function type as a "pointer to function" in the chapter on pointers to functions... Sometimes you have to wonder how familiar the author really is with C++. (Bjarne can be a pretty sloppy writer and, as [the errata](https://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html) says, "The reader is supposed to be sufficiently experienced not to get confused by simple typos."

Comment: That's a risky assumption in an introductory text, but by page 650 it's probably justified.

Comment: You are right, it is an error in the book. Sorry.